# .replaceWith not working in IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I was just testing my webpage in Adobe BrowserLab. I have 3 `.replaceWith` line of jQuery in my webpage, and they're not executing in ie6. The weird part is, I made a jsFiddle with the same jQuery and it worked in Adobe BrowserLab ie6. What's even weirder is that I tested my webpage in ie6 and it worked. But why wouldn't my webpage work in BrowserLab ie6?
Here is the fiddle that works in BrowserLab ie6 and uses the same jQuery code my website uses: http://jsfiddle.net/8CEwf/

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that since I was using jQuery 1.4.2 on my website and jsFiddle was using 1.7.1, that triggered the problem with IE6. Here's the updated fiddle that uses jQuery 1.4.2 and does not work on ie6. http://jsfiddle.net/8CEwf/1/

Comment: Your [jsFiddle at jsfiddle.net/8CEwf/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/8CEwf/1/) is running Mootools and **not** jQuery at all.

Comment: The jQuery file is in the HTML body. This is the answer... I cannot accept it for another two days.

Comment: I don't believe that jQuery is supporting IE6 any longer which might explain why you're seeing it work with 1.4.2 but not 1.7.1.

Comment: Your answer says, _"using 1.7.1 that triggered the problem with IE6"_ and you posted a Fiddle running jQuery 1.4.2 (why post that one if it's not working?).  Perhaps you can clarify the wording of your question and answer.  I thought I understood you before, but now it's just confusing.

Comment: @Sparky672 Sorry, put that comma in there. 1.7.1 did not cause the problem. The problem was that my script wasn't working in ie6 on my site. My site runs 1.4.2. The problem was fixed with jQuery 1.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically speaking, browsers are unique and complex... that's why every version of every browser has it's own rendering quirks, bugs, etc.

Adobe Browser Lab is attempting to replicate each version of every browser, however the Adobe emulator itself could have some bugs, issues, or oversights.

**For testing purposes, you really can't fully trust accurate rendering in anything except the actual browser itself.**

Microsoft provides [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) for free along with [hard drive images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) for every version of Explorer back to IE 6.  I recommend using those above any facsimile.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that, I'm a bit annoyed with BrowserLab because it makes Safari crash... Do they make it for OS X?

Comment: @user1090389, I tried Adobe Browser Lab in Safari for Mac...  IMHO I think it's pretty junky.  If you're asking about Virtual PC for Mac OS X, the answer is no.  You'd simply use BootCamp or Parallels to run a real copy of Windows... then install Virtual PC on Windows and run the various hard drive images from there.  I have a cheap PC running Win XP dedicated just for website testing.